# onchange to create autosave function (javascript) didn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, onchange, autosave

Work by **.click** to save into localStorage:

```
    $("check").onclick = function(){
    parkArray = [check1,check2,check3,check4,check5];
    localStorage.removeItem ("saveArray");     
    localStorage.setItem("saveArray",JSON.stringify(parkArray));
```

Didn't work by **onchange** to autosave into localstorage

```
    parkArray = [check1,check2,check3,check4,check5];
    parkArray.onchange = function () {
    localStorage.removeItem ("saveArray");     
    localStorage.setItem("saveArray",JSON.stringify(parkArray));
```

Can anyone give advise how to solve this if I want Array autosaved when changed?
Thank you.

Original link: https://github.com/erictsaiweb/card-parking/blob/master/cardpark.js

Comment: Is it acceptable for you to use for example AngularJS? or you limited with plain JS?

Comment: Thanks Lugaru. I am open to use all kind of framework if it helps.

Comment: In that case use AngularJS and you can use such staff like $watch or ngChange to dynamically monitor changes without any extra code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to work with an callback function.

```
// initalize
var parkArray = [check1,check2,check3,check4,check5];

// change
changeParkArray([check4,check5,check6,check7,check8], onChangeParkArray);

// change ahain
changeParkArray([check9,check10,check12,check21,check100], onChangeParkArray);


// the function who changes the array
function changeParkArray(newValue, callback){
    parkArray = newValue;
    callback(newValue);
}

// function to run after ParkArray is changed
function onChangeParkArray(data){
    localStorage.removeItem ("saveArray");     
    localStorage.setItem("saveArray",JSON.stringify(data));    
}
```

Comment: Andreas, Thank you! Do you mean:  changeParkArray([new ck1,newck2,newck3,newck4,newck5]  =  function(data){
    localStorage.removeItem ("saveArray");     
    localStorage.setItem("saveArray",JSON.stringify(data));
});

Comment: no, you call the function with 2 parameters. One for the new value and one function that you want to run when the value is changed

Comment: got your point. Check the new value if it changed, right? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not really sure you understand the thing i want to do. I updated the answer. I hope its clear!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the function `onclick` on a jQuery object as it is meant for a JavaScript object (e.g `document.getElementById('element').onclick....`) it should be `.click` or `.on('click')`.

And you're not targeting your element correctly, `check`... Is it a `class` or an `id`...

And `onchange` does not exist in the array prototype. It's only meant for `DOM` object like `input` and `select`.

What you can do for the array is to check if the array `parkArray` is the same as the one in `localStorage`.

e.g

```
$("#check").click(function(){
  var saveArray = (localStorage.saveArray != undefined) ? JSON.parse(localStorage.saveArray) : [];
  parkArray = [check1,check2,check3,check4,check5];

  saveArray.forEach(function(v, i){
    if(parkArray.indexOf(v) < 0){
      localStorage.removeItem ("saveArray");     
      localStorage.setItem("saveArray",JSON.stringify(parkArray));
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Xlander, thanks for your feedback. Let me work on that!